# AWS Userdata script in Cloud Init not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-init

While trying to use the AWS `userdata` option to run a script on instance boot, I noticed that some times (Not always) the cloud init part gets stuck somewhere in the middle and does not reach the part where it runs the user script.

This is how it should look in the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file:

```
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init-local' at Tue, 30 May 2017 06:38:40 +0000. Up 18.56 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init' at Tue, 30 May 2017 06:38:45 +0000. Up 23.39 seconds.
SOME_NETWORK_AND_SSH_KEYS_INFO_HERE
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at Tue, 30 May 2017 06:38:51 +0000. Up 28.80 seconds.
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Tue, 30 May 2017 06:39:35 +0000. Up 73.20 seconds.
MY_USERDATA_SCRIPT_OUTPUT_HERE
```

But here is how it looks when its stuck:

```
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init-local' at Tue, 30 May 2017 06:36:43 +0000. Up 21.80 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init' at Tue, 30 May 2017 06:36:51 +0000. Up 30.13 seconds.
SOME_NETWORK_AND_SSH_KEYS_INFO_HERE
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at Tue, 30 May 2017 06:36:59 +0000. Up 37.66 seconds.
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

As you can see, its stuck after the `Generation complete` and thats it.

Any idea what can cause it and how I should mitigate it?

Btw, OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Add `set -x` to your user-data script so you can see where it's hanging.

Comment: @jordanm it will not help because my script it not even starting. The cloud-init is stuck before

Comment: Why do you believe that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was the another not-related script that was also set to run at the same run-level was stuck, which caused the whole run-level to wait for it to finish before starting the next level (In which module:final is at).

Once we fixed that script the issue was gone.